# A question about definable elements in a model of ZFC

Tags: set-theory

Let $\langle M,E\rangle$ be a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Does there exist a $d\in M$ such that, for all $a\in M$, $a\mathrel{E}d$ if and only if $a$ is definable in $\langle M,E\rangle$ without parameters?

A result of J.D. Hamkins, etc. (cf. [Pointwise definable models of set theory](https://doi.org/10.2178/jsl.7801090)) shows that, for some models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, such a $d$ cannot exist. Is there a model in which such a $d$ exists?

Comment: If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then $(V_\kappa,\in)$ is a model of ZFC in which there is a set $d$ of all elements that are definable without parameters. Since there are only countably many definable elements, their ranks are bounded below $\kappa$, and any subset of $V_\kappa$ with rank below $\kappa$ is an element of $V_\kappa$.

Comment: And by the condensation property, the $V_{\kappa}$ can be replaced with $L_{\kappa}$ in Prof. Blass's answer. Also $\kappa$ can be just inaccessible in $L$.

Comment: Andreas's argument is example (v) on page 146 of the article cited in the OP.

Comment: @Andraes  must be an -model.

Comment: @Greg: How can any $V_\kappa$ *not* be an $\omega$-model?

Comment: @Asaf: If N is a model of ZF, then by compactness there is a conservative extension 
of the theory of N which has no -model. If N is a model of ZF and not an -model,
then Vα is not an -model for any infinite ordinal α.

Comment: @GregKirmayer But it's still true in N that "$V_\alpha$ is an $\omega$-model" because that's a theorem of ZF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the paper you mention in the original post, we mention several of the possibilities as follows. Item (v) includes the particular situation you asked about.

*Hamkins, Joel David; Linetsky, David; Reitz, Jonas*, [**Pointwise definable models of set theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2178/jsl.7801090), J. Symb. Log. 78, No. 1, 139-156 (2013). [ZBL1270.03101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1270.03101). [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/)

> Let us now turn to the question of the extent to which
>   definability is first-order expressible, by presenting a
>   number of examples that illustrate the range of
>   possibility. We have already observed that the property of
>   a model being pointwise definable is not first order
>   expressible, since it is not preserved by nontrivial
>   elementary extensions. Since pointwise definability is a
>   strong generalization of the axiom $V=\newcommand\HOD{\text{HOD}}\HOD$, it is tempting
>   to introduce such notation as $V=D$ or $V=HD$ to express
>   that a model is pointwise definable, thereby maintaining a
>   parallel to the classical $V=\HOD$ notation while
>   emphasizing that the definitions need no parameters. We
>   hesitate to adopt this notation, however, because we fear
>   it would incorrectly suggest that the concept is
>   first-order expressible, which isn't the case.
>
> (i) *There is no uniform definition of the class of
>   definable elements.* Specifically, there is no formula
>   $\mathop{\rm df}(x)$ in the language of set theory that is
>   satisfied in any model $M\newcommand\satisfies{\models}\satisfies\newcommand\ZFC{\text{ZFC}}\ZFC$ exactly by the
>   definable elements. The reason is that if $M_0$ is
>   pointwise definable and $M_0\prec M$ is a nontrivial
>   elementary extension, then the definable elements of $M_0$
>   and $M$ are precisely the elements of $M_0$, and so $M_0$
>   should satisfy $\forall x\,\mathop{\rm df}(x)$ but $M$
>   would satisfy $\exists x\,\neg \mathop{\rm df}(x)$,
>   contrary to $M_0\prec M$.
>
> (ii) *The class of definable elements can form a
>   definable class.* Although there is no uniform definition
>   of the class of definable elements, it can sometimes happen
>   that a model enjoys a certain structure that allows it to
>   see its collection of definable elements as a definable
>   class. For example, in a pointwise definable model, the
>   class of definable elements includes every object and is
>   therefore defined by the formula $x=x$. See also (iv) and
>   (v) below.
>
> (iii) *The collection of definable elements might
>        not form a class.* Consider any model
>        $M\satisfies\ZFC$, and let $N$ be an ultrapower of
>        $M$ by an ultrafilter on the natural numbers. The
>        parameter-free definable elements of $N$ are
>        necessarily contained in the range of the
>        ultrapower map, and in particular, do not include
>        any of the newly added nonstandard natural
>        numbers. Thus, the class of definable elements of
>        $N$ is not amenable to $N$, for it would reveal
>        that its natural number are not well-founded.
>
> (iv) *The definable elements can form a definable
>        class in a model having no class function $r\mapsto\psi_r$
>        mapping definable elements to definitions.* Suppose
>        that $M$ is a pointwise definable model of $\ZFC$.
>        The definable elements of $M$ are all of $M$,
>        which is certainly a definable class in $M$. But
>        $M$ cannot have a function $r\mapsto\psi_r$
>        associating to each element $r$ of $M$, or even to
>        each real of $M$, a defining formula $\psi_r$,
>        since such a map would reveal to $M$ that it has
>        only countably many reals.
>
> (v) *The definable elements can be a set in a model
>   that does have a definability map $r\mapsto\psi_r$.* 
>   Suppose that $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal (this
>   hypothesis can be reduced), and observe by a
>   Lowenheim-Skolem argument that there are numerous
>   $\gamma<\kappa$ with $V_\gamma\prec
> V_\kappa\satisfies\ZFC$. It follows that the definable
>   elements of $V_\kappa$ are all in $V_\gamma$ and satisfy
>   the same definitions there as in $V_\kappa$. Since
>   $V_\gamma$ is a set in $V_\kappa$, we may construct in
>   $V_\kappa$     the function $r\mapsto \psi_r$ that maps
>   every     definable element $r$ of $V_\gamma$ to the
>   smallest definition $\psi_r$ of it, and because
>   $V_\gamma\prec V_\kappa$, this function has the same
>   property with respect to $V_\kappa$, as desired. The large
>   cardinal hypothesis can be reduced; it is sufficient to
>   have an $\omega$-model $M$ with some $M_0\in M$ having
>   $M_0\prec M$.
>
> (vi) *No model can have a **definable** definability
>   map $r\mapsto\psi_r$.* If such a map were definable, then
>   since there are only countably many definitions $\psi_r$,
>   we could easily diagonalize against it to produce a
>   definable real not in the domain of the map. In (v), the
>   map is definable from parameter $\gamma$.
>
> The surviving content of the math-tea argument seems to be
>   the observation that in any model with access to a
>   definability map $r\mapsto\psi_r$, the definable reals do
>   not exhaust all the reals.

Comment: Talk about covering all bases...

Comment: @Joel The sufficient condition you give is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

For definiteness we say that $a$ is definable in a model $\langle M,E\rangle$ of ZF if there is a formula $\varphi$ with one free variable in the language with one non-logical symbol $\in$ with the property that $\langle M,E\rangle\models\phi(x)$ iff $x=a$. (The Gödel number of such a formula must be standard.)

The condition given by Joel David Hamkins in the last sentence of (v)
of his answer is necessary and sufficient for there to be a set in $M$ consisting of the definable elements of $M$:

> **Theorem.** For any model $\langle M,E\rangle\models\mathrm{ZF}$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists a $d\in M$ such that for all $a\in M$, $a\mathrel{E}d$ if and only if $a$ is definable in $\langle M,E\rangle$.
> 2. $M$ is an $\omega$-model, and there is $N\in M$ such that $N\prec M$.

**Proof:**

**1 → 2:** Suppose $d\in M$, and for all $a\in M$, $a\mathrel{E}d$ if and only if $a$ is definable in $\langle M,E\rangle$.

> **Claim.** Let $M\models\text{“$\alpha$ is the least ordinal not in $d$”}$. Then $V_\alpha^M\prec M$.

**Proof:** Write $V_\alpha$ for $V_\alpha^M$. We prove
$$\forall p_1,\dots,p_n\in V_\alpha\:\bigl(V_\alpha\models\phi(p_1,\dots,p_n)\iff M\models\phi(p_1,\dots,p_n)\bigr)\tag1$$
by induction on the complexity of $\phi$. For atomic formulas $\phi$, (1) holds.

Suppose that (1) holds for $\phi$ and $\psi$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
V_\alpha\models\phi\land\psi&
\iff(V_\alpha\models\phi\text{ and }V_\alpha\models\psi)\\
&\iff(M\models\phi\text{ and }M\models\psi)
\iff M\models\phi\land\psi.
\end{align*}$$
Also,
$$V_\alpha\models\neg\phi\iff ¬V_\alpha\models\phi\iff ¬M\models\phi\iff M\models\neg\phi.$$

Suppose (1) holds for $\theta(x,\dots)$. If $V_\alpha\models\exists x\,\theta(x,p_1,\dots,p_n)$, then $V_\alpha\models\theta(p,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ for some $p\mathrel{E}V_\alpha$. Therefore $M\models\theta(p,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ and so $M\models\exists x\,\theta(x,p_1,\dots,p_n)$.

Finally, suppose $M\models\exists x\,\theta(x,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ for $p_i$ in $V_\alpha$. Then there is an ordinal $\delta$ in $d$ such that $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ is contained in $V_\delta$. $\beta\mathrel{E}d$ must hold for the least ordinal $\beta$ such that $\delta\mathrel{E}\beta$, $V_\beta$ reflects $\exists x\,\theta$, and $V_\beta$ reflects $\theta$. Therefore $M\models\theta(p,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ for some $p\mathrel{E}V_\beta$, and consequently $V_\alpha\models\theta(p,p_1,\dots,p_n)$, and thus $V_\alpha\models\exists x\,\theta(x,p_1,\dots,p_n)$.

This completes the proof of the Claim. It remains to prove that $M$ is an $\omega$-model.

For each $a\mathrel{E}d$, let $g_a$ be the least Gödel number of a formula which defines $a$ in $V_\alpha$. There is a set $S\in M$ consisting of the $g_a$ for which $a\mathrel{E}d$. Since $S$ is an infinite set of standard natural numbers, its union must be $\omega$. Thus, $\omega\in M$, and $M$ is an $\omega$-model.

**2 → 1:** Suppose $M$ is an $\omega$-model, $N\in M$ and $N\prec M$. There is a $d\in M$ such that $b\mathrel{E}d$ iff $b\mathrel{E}N$ and
$M\models\text{“$b$ is definable in $N$”}$. Then $b\mathrel{E}d$ if and only if $b$ is definable in $\langle M,E\rangle$.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat the answer to make it readable, and clarify the structure of the proof.

Comment: I retained the original proof of the Claim, but note that everything except the last paragraph (“Finally, ...”) can be removed if you just appeal to the Tarski–Vaught test instead.

Comment: @Emil: Thank you. I think anyone who reads this answer will benefit from your work.