# A question regarding the "math tea" argument

Tags: set-theory, definability

Joel David Hamkins published a paper where he analyzes the "math tea" argument, namely, the argument that some real numbers are undefinable. He constructed a countable model of set theory where all sets are definable without parameters, and this apparently shows the flaw with the math tea argument. However, I still think some real numbers are undefinable. Here is why. Since we know that, "in the real universe", the real numbers are uncountable, they can't fit inside a countable model $M$, even if $M$ thinks the set of reals in that model are internally uncountable. So, basically, I think any countable model of set theory will never have all of the "real" real numbers, and this is why I think some real numbers are undefinable. I would like some clarification of this, and want to be corrected if I misunderstand something.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354201/a-question-about-definable-elements-in-a-model-of-zfc/354234

Comment: Definitely relevant: http://karagila.org/2015/name-that-number/

Comment: The problem is that, if you are assuming a true ambient universe where the "real" real numbers live, in that universe, you cannot even state the math-tea argument due to Tarski undefinability.

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3954453/28111.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In both this and in Hamkins' paper, I don't understand why the simple requirement of needing to use a finite number of symbols is immediately abandoned. The argument seems to me to be a kind of "in principle" argument, ignoring the fact that it is not in fact possible to uniquely specify every real number. It strikes me as misinterpreting the math tea argument.

Comment: @Era: I have to admit, I couldn't really follow your argument here. The point is that "uniquely specify" does not tell you anything about the language or "in what structure". Specifying an object depends on the structure (including the language)!